# PHP XML data for insert query

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have following xml data printed as array in php so now I want to convert this XML data and make insert query so how to do that as I am not so good with XML so if anyone out there who can write the sample code to convert this XML array into columns and data as part of sql query.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
```

(
    [request] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [type] => City
            [query] => Auckland, New Zealand
        )

```
[weather] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-07-01
                [astronomy] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [sunrise] => 07:35 AM
                        [sunset] => 05:15 PM
                        [moonrise] => 04:37 PM
                        [moonset] => 06:07 AM
                    )

                [maxtempC] => 15
                [maxtempF] => 60
                [mintempC] => 10
                [mintempF] => 50
                [uvIndex] => 0
```

Now here is php code which produce the above print_r($xml);

PHP code:

```
$xml_response = file_get_contents($premiumurl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
```

Now, if anyone can write further code and make one insert query with columns and rows....it will be really great and yes I tried many solution and even looked at some tutorial but couldn;t learn or resolve this. Thank you in advanced.

SQL query in php will e something like following just writing it so someone get idea:

```
 $columns ="";
foreach($xml as $column){
    $columns .= (string)$column->attributes()->name .",";
}
$columns = rtrim($columns, ",");

$values ="";
foreach($xml->column as $value){
    $values .= $value ."," ;
}
$values = rtrim($values, ",");

$query = " INSERTO INTO  $table ( $columns ) VALUES ( $values ) ";   

echo $query;
```

Thank you guys :) in advanced

Comment: Can you post full data of `XML` you receive?

Comment: It's too long as it's the data of weather and by day and time so it will be too long

Comment: no issue can you give value of `$premiumurl` to let me test before providing solution.

Comment: Hi I cannot post thr $premiumurl as its contain key which I can't share it here and secondly I want conversion from XML to PHP more likely but still what I do for you paste the XML code

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your query

Change from

```
$query = " INSERTO INTO  $table ( $columns ) VALUES ( $values ) ";
```

To

```
$query = " INSERT INTO  $table ( $columns ) VALUES ( $values ) ";
```